# Create EMR 5.3.0 with EMRFS (s3 bucket) as storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, emr, amazon-emr

I'm trying to create EMR 5.3.0 with EMRFS (S3 bucket) as storage.
Please provide your general guidance regarding this.

Currently i'm using below command for creating EMR 5.3.0 with InstanceType=m4.2xlarge.Which is working fine, but with EMRFS as storage i'm not able to do

`aws emr create-cluster --name "DEMAPAUR001" 
    --release-label emr-5.3.0 
    --service-role EMR_DefaultRole_Private 
    --enable-debug 
    --log-uri 's3n://xyz/trn'
    --ec2-attributes SubnetId=subnet-545e8823,
     KeyName=XXX 
    --applications Name=Hbase Name=Hive Name=Pig Name=Ganglia
    --configurations '[{"Classification":"hdfs-site","Properties": 
       {"dfs.replication":"2"},"Configurations":[]}]' 
   --instance-groups

   'InstanceGroupType=MASTER,InstanceCount=1,InstanceType=m4.2xlarge,
   EbsConfiguration={EbsOptimized=true,
   EbsBlockDeviceConfigs=[{VolumeSpecification=                                {VolumeType=io1,SizeInGB=500,Iops=200},VolumesPerInstance=1}]}'
  'InstanceGroupType=CORE,
   InstanceCount=1,InstanceType=m4.2xlarge,EbsConfiguration={EbsOptimized=true,
   EbsBlockDeviceConfigs=[{VolumeSpecification={VolumeType=io1,SizeInGB=500,Iops=200},VolumesPerInstance=1}]}'
   --tags Name=DEMAPAUR001 Owner="XXX" Division=Corporate Application=DEM-EMR    Environment=TRN CostCenter=XXX123 CreatedBy=XXX ManagedBy=XXX  Availability=24x7_Mon-Fri Backup=NA`

Kindly help me regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following classification in the configuration while launching the cluster.

For enabling consistent view

{
                                "Classification": "emrfs-site",
                                "Properties": {
                                    "fs.s3.consistent": "true"
                                }
                            }

Also, if you actually want hive to point to S3 and store all new files there, you will have to add this classification to hive-site.xml

{
                                "Classification": "hive-site",
                                "Properties": {
                                    "hive.metastore.warehouse.dir": self.hive_warehouse_dir
                                }
                            }

Comment: "Which is working fine, but with EMRFS as storage i'm not able to do." With EMRFS as storage of what? I'm confused by your question/problem. What exactly are you trying to do, and what is the problem that is occurring? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: Can you please clarify the answer?